How to delete my account?
I am considering deleting my account in chinese.stachexchange.com (but not other Stackexchange accounts) --- not now, but perhaps in the near future. In math.stachexchange.com, we only need to add the sentence "please delete me" in our profiles to notify the mods/admins for our requests, but I don't see any way to delete an account on this site.

Great question. I'd like to know as well.

See this: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account


Go to the bottom of any page on the Chinese SE site.
There should be a "contact us" option.
There should be an account deletion request option, and only your account on this site will be deleted. (If you want, you can specify that on the "additional comments" (or something similar) box if you want to be extra sure.)

I believe there were also instructions to replace the text in your "about me" box with "please delete this account", but if I remember correctly (from my experience with quitting some sites that didn't interest me enough) that's not the "main" step.

Thank you very much. I will try to delete my account right away.

@user1551: there is a 24 hour (or so) wait period (I think they also send out an email some point afterwards) but that should more or less do the trick.

Yes. I have submitted my request and a message says that there will be email notification. Thanks again for your help.
